# Django template : Need 2 values to unpack in for loop; got 8

Tags: python, django, templates, render

Through my view I collected some data that I want to bundle together in a list of values that look like this :

```
data = [(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8),(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8),(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)]
```

Then I'll be rendering that to my template to unpack the data to my page :

```
return render(request, 'accounts/page.html', {'data' : data})
```

Template goes like this :

```
{% for a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h in data %}
    <h3>{{a}}</h3>
    <h3>{{b}}</h3>
    #and so on
    #..
    <h3>{{h}}</h3>
{% endfor %}
```

So the error i get is :

Need 2 values to unpack in for loop; got 8.

Can anyone figure out the source of this error or maybe have a better way of rendering data in bundles ?

Thanks !

Comment: The `list` is never passed, since the context should be a *dictionary* that maps *names* to items. So here Django would never know that there is a variable with the name `list`.

Comment: You could just use nested loops. It's gotta do that under the hood anyways with the unpacking.

Comment: I'll experiment with nested loops

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Be careful to not use `list` as variable it is depreciated since it is a Python Type Object(reserved)
And the problem is only in your render:

```
my_list = [(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8),(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8),(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)]
return render(request, 'accounts/page.html', {'my_list': my_list})
```

Comment: Thks @Wariored actually i was sloppy, my render is correct in the real program this is just an example. here my real render which i assume correct : args = {'form': form, 'annonces':annonces, 'rech':len(annonces)} // return render(request, 'accounts/page_recherche.html', args). 
Still i have the same problem though :/

Comment: @Djamel can I see your entire view?

Comment: Sure, where can I send it to you ? (sorry new to stack overflow i'm not sure if there a messaging service here)

Comment: You can just  ask a new question. Then post the link here as comment

Comment: here's the new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51637418/django-template-need-2-values-to-unpack-in-for-loop-got-many

Answer (score 3):

The context passed to render should be a `dict`

```
return render(request, 'accounts/page.html', {'list': list})
```

Comment: thks, I've updated the question, the problem persists though

Answer (score 0):

You need to zip the list and pass it as a dict:

```
list = zip([(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8),(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8),(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)])
return render(request, 'accounts/page.html', {'list':list})
```

Comment: You don't need to zip it but the dict part is correct.

Comment: thks, I've updated the question, the problem persists though