# Django template : Need 2 values to unpack in for loop; got many

Tags: python, django, templates, render

So to update my previous question : 
[Django template : Need 2 values to unpack in for loop; got 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51633309/django-template-need-2-values-to-unpack-in-for-loop-got-8?noredirect=1#comment90238306_51633533)

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect   
from accounts.forms import Searchform 
import requests

page=''
ville =''
region=''
prixmin =''
prixmax= ''
surfacemin='' 
surfacemax=''
def post(request):
    global page ,ville ,prixmin ,prixmax, surfacemin, surfacemax, region, annonces
    if request.method == 'POST':    
        form = Searchform(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            ville = form.cleaned_data['ville']          
            prixmin = form.cleaned_data['prix_min']
            prixmax = form.cleaned_data['prix_max']
            surfacemax = form.cleaned_data['surface_max']
            surfacemin = form.cleaned_data['surface_min']
    else:
        page='1'
        form = Searchform()

    annonces = []

    try:
        url = 'example'
        img = 'example'
        ville = 'example'
        typeImmo = 'example'    
        Nb_piece = 'example'
        Nb_ch = 'example'
        surface = 'example'
        prix = 'example'
        annonces.append((url,img,ville,typeImmo,Nb_piece,Nb_ch,surface,prix))
    except:pass

    args = {'form': form, 'annonces':annonces, 'rech':len(annonces)}
    return render(request, 'accounts/page_recherche.html', args)
```

and then I will unpack the data in annonces to use it in my template.

```
                {% for annonce in annonces %}
            <div class="col">
                <div class="card" style="width: 33rem;">
                    <div class="row">

                        <div class="col">
                              <a href="{{annonce.0}}" target="_blank">
                                <img class="card-img-top" src="{{annonce.1}}" alt="No image" height="180">
                              </a>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col">     
                          <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
                            <li class="list-group-item">{{annonce.2}}</li>
                            <li class="list-group-item">{{annonce.6}} - {{annonce.4}}</li>
                            <li class="list-group-item">{{annonce.7}}</li>
                          </ul>
                       </div>
                </div>      
            </div>
            {% endfor %}
```

Sorry for the style of my code I'm new at programming and at python. Any pro tips for writing better code are much appreciated ;)

Thks !

Comment: Please share your template code.

Comment: Add the traceback.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem added

Comment: @SachinKukreja what is a traceback ?

Comment: Error stack trace. The whole bunch of errors in your server logs which you have posted in one of the answers in comments.

Comment: What is your Django version?

Comment: Django Version: 2.0.3

Comment: Your **try/except** updates many of your variables. All results will have as value 'exemple'

Answer (score 1):

In your template use

```
{% for i in annonces %}
    <h3>{{i.0}}</h3>
    <h3>{{i.1}}</h3>
    #and so on
    #..
    <h3>{{i.8}}</h3>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: same : Need 2 values to unpack in for loop; got 8. 
Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/
Django Version: 2.0.3
Exception Type: ValueError
Exception Value: 
Need 2 values to unpack in for loop; got 8. 
Exception Location: C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py in render, line 202
Python Executable: C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\python.exe
Python Version: 3.6.4

Answer (score 1):

There is two ways:
First one:

```
{% for i in annonces %}
    <h3>{{i.0}}</h3>
    <h3>{{i.1}}</h3>
    #and so on
    #..
    <h3>{{i.7}}</h3>
{% endfor %}
```

Second one

```
{% for a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h in annonces %}
    <h3>{{a}}</h3>
    <h3>{{a}}</h3>
    #and so on
    #..
    <h3>{{h}}</h3>
{% endfor %}
```